# Problem with empty, non-required Assets 2.1 field in a Matrix row

Tags: assets, matrix

I upgraded to Assets 2.1 yesterday and am experiencing a problem when a non-required Assets 2.1 field in a Matrix row is empty. On a single-entry template **(limit=“1” and require_entry=“yes” parameters in my exp:channel:entries tag)** this situation is causing the {if no_results} conditional to be invoked. Selecting a file for the empty, non-required, Assets field and re-saving the entry fixes the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Matrix 2.5.3
ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 Build 20120606

Here is template code that will trigger the issue:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" limit="1" status="open" disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data" require_entry="yes"}{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Videos</h2>

{sidebar_videos limit="1"}

<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{youtube_video_id}"></iframe>
<p>{youtube_caption}</p>

{/sidebar_videos}

<h3>All Videos</h3>

<ul id="videothumbs">

{sidebar_videos}

<li><a href="/features/videos/{entry_id}/{row_id}" title="{youtube_title}”>{youtube_thumbnail}<img src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}">{/youtube_thumbnail}</a></li>

{/sidebar_videos}

</ul>

</body>
</html>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

`{sidebar_videos}` is my Matrix field, which is not required. `{youtube_thumbnail}` is the problem Assets field within the Matrix field. The other columns in the Matrix field are:

`{youtube_title}` (Text/required)

`{youtube_video_id}` (Text/required)

`{youtube_caption}` (Wygwam/required)

`{youtube_thumbnail}` (Assets/not required)

Comment: Hey jauses - can you post your full template code? I'd like to test this and want to make sure I'm recreating what you've done.  Thank you!

Comment: Updated my real answer with the fix for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit again!  jauses - can you try changing line 1324 in ft.assets.php file from

```
if (! $data)
```

to

```
if (! $data && $this->var_id)
```

?  That should fix this up for you.

Thank you!

Comment: I can replicate that problem, too. It’s actually failing even if I limit the output to a single entry that has a populated Assets field. The required_entry parameter seems to be the problem child here. Removing it fixes the problem, although then, of course, the {if no_results} conditional fails.

Comment: Yep, it's an interesting one - I have submitted it as a bug for 2.1  Thank you jauses!

Comment: Boom! That did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure, jauses!